# video list - getYoutubeService() returns null

Tags: java

I am developing Android application for youtube channel. I want to retrieve all videos for a channel. Copied full code  from the Youtube Data API website(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

Facing different kind of errors like:

- java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found.
- unable to create directory: /.credentials/java-youtube-api-tests
  at the end it return null response.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: looks like a ssl problem. Have a close look at the ssh handshake.

Comment: Sure, Thanks for response